# How can I create Android service all time working

Tags: android, android-service

I want create Android service all time working to when I stopped it. Restart device, Garbage collector and etc don't affect it's working. Advice me best example please.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground

Comment: I already looked Foreground(). I don't want showing icon in notification bar. I want work only background

Comment: There is no other way. Android OS can kill any service if it feels hungry only exception is foreground service

Comment: I know Android can kill, I thing restart service when killed ( onDestroy() ). Restart service when restrat device complate and etc. Best way thats doing

Comment: @Farid Wallyev You can't circumvent the Android rules. You can't have a foreground service and hide it from the user - if that was possible (it was a while back), people would be abusing it and keeping their apps running forever so they launch faster, jeopardizing the whole system. What you are trying to do appears to be sneaky and against the rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a `BroadcastReceiver` that listens for the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast `Intent` and start your `Service` when the device boots.

Your `Service` should return `START_STICKY` from `onStartCommand()`. This will restart your `Service` if Android decides to kill it for any reason.

You cannot prevent Android from killing your `Service` if it wants to. All you can do is try to make sure that your `Service` gets restarted if killed.

Also, if your user force stops your application, your `Service` will be stopped and will not be automatically started again. In this case, the user will need to launch your app again in order for you to restart your `Service`.

Comment: some device does't work. How can I  fix it all device?

Comment: You need to be more specific. What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What is happening? If Android isn't restarting your `Service` after it is killed even though you return `START_STICKY`, then you will need to schedule a kind of "watchdog". Schedule a repeated alarm that starts your `Service`. This will restart your `Service` in case Android isn't doing it properly. However, if the user force stops your application, this won't restart it either.

Comment: it's mean some device service kill and service can't restart. I returned 'START_STICKY'

Comment: Strange, it shouldn't do that. In any case, you can try my suggested solution (using a watchdog).

Answer (score 2):

- You must return **START_STICKY** in method **onStartCommand**() (or just create [Foreground Service](http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/guide/components/services.html#Foreground) with a notification in status bar, it will run all time even if low memory, eg: music player use forceground service to make sure the  music always plays)
- After device **reboot**, you must **broastcat** this event and start your service.
- In **non root device**, your service can be stopped by an orther app (eg: Cleanmaster), **but** if you return START_STICKY, it will auto restart. With non root device, your service will be stopped when user **Force stop** your application (in App manager setting). To prevent user force stop your application, you can request user grant [Device Administration](http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) permission with your app.
- In **rooted device**, cannot prevent CleanMaster Force stop your app even if you return START_STICKY or granted Device Administration because this app maybe have granted SuperUser permission.

Answer (score 1):

For this you will have to set a BroadcastReciver which will receive boot completed. in that receiver start the service you want following is exact code.

Service class

```
public class BroadCastService extends Service {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.tone);
        mediaPlayer.start();
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

BroadCastReciver class

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, BroadCastService.class);
        context.startService(startServiceIntent);
   }
}
```

inside Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
// add following in <application>
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```